# Maps API Panoramio layer - panoramioLayer.setUserID

Tags: google-maps, layer, panoramio

I've been trying to use setUserID to filter Panoramio for photos according to user, using the PanoramioLayer in the Google Maps API. I came across a thread on Google Groups which seemed to answer the question (for ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/5d78gwxnP3k ), and have read the Maps API documentation, but it simply doesn't work; I've searched further and found nothing else that gives any idea about what may be wrong with my code:

```
  var panoramioLayer = new google.maps.panoramio.PanoramioLayer();
  panoramioLayer.setUserID("Philoramio");
  panoramioLayer.setMap(map);
```

I've tried swapping in different UserIDs on the offchance that elements within specific IDs were causing problems (or that my ID wasn't searchable, or valid), but no joy - I just get a blank map with no pictures every time. I've done obvious things like flushing my cache, using different browsers, but same results.

I have had limited success by swapping setUserID with setTag and getting images displayed via tags (this brings up photos with corresponding tags, although none of my own have shown up, which is another issue), so I'm pretty sure the code I'm using is otherwise OK. At the moment I simply want to get setUserID to work with ANY user ID, and work from there!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ID is an integer. You can see it in address to your panoramio page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem.  Turns out you DO need quotes for the userid, not the name of the user like you tried to do.  Like this...

```
var panoramioLayer = new google.maps.panoramio.PanoramioLayer();
panoramioLayer.setMap(map);
panoramioLayer.setUserId("7916283");
```